Child component Blazor keeping data alive after rerender
Hello i am developing a Maui Blazor App but is just behave as blazor using net 8
I have several nested components, when i fecth data i got the initial payload, then i can modify this data delete or adding more data, the problem occurs when i try to reset to the initial payload clicking search bottom again without commiting changes to the data. the modified data still remains, i would like the data resets to the inital payload
Edit:
I have found that private fields with data survive after a rerender in a component
Here is an issue reproduction, in this example i fecth the data from FakeApi, inside Component Tags can view the original data plus the data added in this comoponent, also is possible to use eventcallbacks to add or remove from the original source. If i refresh the data to initial data clcikcing again Search (FakeAPI) the data inside of manageTags survives it shuold be reset.
Data
 public class Data
 {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public double Age { get; set; }
 }

FakeApi
public class FakeApi : IFakeApi
{
    public List<Data> GetData()
    {
        return new List<Data> { new Data { Id = 1, Age = 20, Name = "Edgar" }, new Data { Id = 2, Age = 45, Name = "Peter" } };
    }
}

Page
@page "/counter"
@inject IFakeApi FakeApi

<PageTitle>Manage users</PageTitle>

<button @onclick="Search">Search (FakeAPI)</button>

@if(_data is not null)
{
    @foreach(var item in _data)
    {
        <p>@item.Id - @item.Age - @item.Name </p> 
    }
}

<BlazorApp2.Components.ManageTags _datas="_data" OnAdd="OnAdd" OnRemove="OnRemove" />


@code {
    private List<Data> _data { get; set; }
    private bool SHowHideResumeNewTags { get; set; } = false;

    private async Task Search()
    {
        _data = FakeApi.GetData();
    }

    public void OnAdd(Data item)
    {
        _data.Add(item);
    }

    public void OnRemove(Data item)
    {
        _data.Remove(item);
    }
}

Manage Tags(use a Blazor.Bootstrap V2.2.0 to create a modal window)
<button @onclick="OnShowModalClick">ManageTags</button>

<Modal @ref="modal" title="Item" Size="ModalSize.ExtraLarge">
    <BodyTemplate>
        @foreach(var item in _datas)
        {
            <p>@item.Id - @item.Age - @item.Name </p> <button @onclick="() => Remove(item)">Remove</button>
        }
        <p>Local</p>
        @foreach (var item in _localItem)
        {
            <p>@item.Id - @item.Age - @item.Name </p> <button @onclick="() => Remove(item)">Remove</button>
        }
        <button @onclick="Add">Add Random</button>
    </BodyTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        <Button Color="ButtonColor.Secondary" @onclick="OnHideModalClick">Cerrar</Button>
    </FooterTemplate>
</Modal>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public List<Data> _datas { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<Data> OnAdd { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<Data> OnRemove { get; set; }

    private List<Data> _localItem { get; set; } = new List<Data>();

    private Modal modal = default!;

    private async Task OnHideModalClick()
    {
        await modal.HideAsync();
    }

    private async Task OnShowModalClick()
    {
        await modal.ShowAsync();
    }

    private async Task Add()
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int num = rnd.Next();
        var item = new Data { Age = num, Id = num, Name = num.ToString() };
        await OnAdd.InvokeAsync(item);
        _localItem.Add(item);
    }

    private async Task Remove(Data item)
    {
        _localItem.Remove(item);
        await OnRemove.InvokeAsync(item);
    }
}


This is just a wall of code with no context for anyone trying to read it.  I gave up.  You probably need to condense it down to some form of [MRE].

@MrCakaShaunCurtis i update the post with a minimal implemetaion reproducing the issue

OK, now tell us what are the expected and the actual results. Your _localItem(s) is not in sync, but that is by design?

@HenkHolterman I would like to see the info of _localItems in the modal, but i soon as the main data is reload those local changes has to be lost, the reason to see the localITems in the modal is to see the actual data that you are working.
